# Looking for pathing algorithms for maps without edges

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm

I have 2D world maps that are basically Mercator-Like projections, (If you walk west long enough you end up east of where you started)

Question I have: Can you use A* for computing paths on these types of maps as well?

I can't think of any reason why you couldn't (I'm thinking that you would simply represent the edge map nodes such that the North, South, East, Wed, "border" nodes simply connected to the opposite side).

Thanks in advance, if anyone has seen something like this before or can give me a few hints I would appreciate it.

Comment: maybe you should ask here too: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pathfinding algorithms don't really care about global topology of the map. The only tricky part is to get a good estimator for A* but using the 3D distance should be ok if your map is indeed a surface in a 3d space and step cost is step length.

Your map can have all sort of strange "connections" (including for example knotted bridges) and this will not be a problem if you implement A* correctly.

Comment: Although really weird and irregular teleportation points may make creating a good the heuristic (and thus, keeping search space low) much harder - especially when the shortcuts can change dynamically.

Comment: @delnan: True. That's why I said "if your map is a surface in a 3d space and your step cost is step length". Clearly if you have a "teleport" then step cost is not step length.

Comment: @6502 Thank you for your answer, I'll pursue an A* implementation

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine why a Mercator-Like projections would cause a problem for A*, as long as your  heuristic function approximates distances correctly.  I think something along the below function should work fine

```
float heuristic(point from, point to, size mapsize) {
    float x = from.x - to.x;
    if (abs(x) > mapsize.x/2)
        x = mapsize.x - x;
    float y = from.y - to.y;
    if (abs(y) > mapsize.y/2)
        y = mapsize.y - y;
    return sqrt(x*x+y*y);
}
```

Comment: Please test it first, I'm not 100% confident in it.

Comment: Think that should use `x = mapsize.x - x` and `y = mapsize.y - y` in the if statement blocks.

Comment: No, I mean it's flat-out wrong. If for argument's sake `mapsize.x` is 1.0 and the `x`-differential is 0.6, and if the `from` point is positioned right on the x-edge, then basically you should be able to go 0.6 one way and 0.4 the other way to get to it. (In other words, both paths should end up adding to the size of the map.) So you should be using the entire `mapsize` value rather than half of it.

Comment: Also, given the same paramters, `mapsize.x / 2` is equal to 0.5, and 0.5 - 0.6 is equal to -0.1, which is just weird. Yes, negative numbers will work in the distance formula thanks to the squaring, but the absolute value itself is just plain wrong.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure so are you saying that the heuristic can exceed the actual distance?

Comment: I'm just saying the heuristic gives bad values and is misleading. It is not proportional to the actual travel distance. Think of how a unit circle words when you're trying to measure an acute angle: If the angle is too great (greater than 1/2 of the circle arc), you get the acute angle by subtracting from the full arc. The same pattern applies here.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: You're correct, I'd forgotten to take the aboslute value (for when `from.x > to.x`), and subtracted from `mapsize.x/2` instead of `mapsize.x`.  Now if `from.x = .9`, `to.x=.2`, and `mapsize.x=1`, then `x = -0.7`.  Since `.7 > .5`, then `x = .3`, which is the correct distance.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**: I realize know I was misled by the *non-graph theoretical*) use of the word *edge* (where the question title strongly suggested a graph algorithm question :))

<sub><strike>Why do you suppose there are no edges? There are many logical discrete locations that you could model, and limited connections between (i.e. not where a wall is :)). There you go: you have your edges.</strike></sub>

What you probably mean is that you don't want to represent your edges in data (which you don't have to, but still there are the logical edges that connect locations/points.)

#### That said:

you ask whether someone has seen things like this before. I vaguely recall seeing something relevant to this in Knuths `Dancing Links` article (DLX) which is an implementation technique for A* algorithms.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links
- [original publication [PDF]](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/papers/dancing-color.ps.gz)

The article specifically treats states as 'cells' (in a grid) with east/west/north/south links. It's been a long time so I don't quite recall how you would map (no pun intended) your problem on that algorithm.

> **The dance steps**. One good way to implement algorithm X is to represent each 1 in the
>   matrix A as a data object x with five fields L[x]; R[x]; U [x]; D[x]; C[x]. Rows of the matrix
>   are doubly linked as circular lists via the L and R fields ("left" and "right"); columns are
>   doubly linked as circular lists via the U and D fields ("up" and "down"). Each column
>   list also includes a special data object called its list header.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure Dancing Links is an implementation technique for AlgorithmX to solve exact cover problems, are you sure it can do A* too?

Comment: I remember them as 1 and the same thing. Now I might be completely off the tracks, but it was an honest memory. Basically: no, i'm not sure. Just hoping that the OP would be able to recognize a potential match. If someone can pinpoint the mismatch or any big error on my side, I'll be happy to delete the answer tough.

Comment: reworded my intro of Dancing Links raise fewer expectations :)

Comment: @sehe Sorry about that! I'll try and be more careful with my question wording in the future.